# Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord save a record fields as a different user then the user called the Api

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, xrm

This the context and the problem I am facing( I am using Dynamics 365 CE v9.x 2021 wave 1 release update)

To save the sales order data and close the sales order I am going to do it via JavaScript Xrm.WebApi.UpdateRecord.

Then I am going to look at the audit history and I see the user who did the change is not the user that performed the WebApi update request :O

Do you have any idea why?
Could be some user or system setting?
A bug by Microsoft?

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide an example of some of your code.  Maybe the part where you update an entry.

Comment: Xrm.WebApi.UpdateRecord uses the context of the current user, if you see a different user inside the audit history (and there are no other code like a plugin that can interfere inside the update operation) then you should open a support ticket to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone one thanks a lot for your answer.

I fixed the problem. It was more complicated then excepted.

The JavaScript failed to change the status of the sales order.

To close as completed a sales order an other message request should be executed.

In the mean time a workflow was triggered on the business process flow entity related to that sales order when the bpf status is changed.

So I changed the workflow and I changed the JavaScript.

I am testing this change I will go to show it to our global super user to see if any use cases are missing in the bug fix
Thank you Guido thank you chrwhal